# Как скачать видео из Rutube с помощью youtube-dl?

Tags: видео, youtube, download

Возможно ли скачать Rutube-видео c помощью youtube-dl? Если возможно, как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, возможно! А почему нет?!

`youtube-dl -i https://rutube.ru/video/85d87bd294aceb659cb5c8b1cd7ccefd/`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за ключ -i ?

Comment: -i, --ignore-errors -> Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist

Comment: Просто качаю из YT плейлистами, и вот, качаешь например плейлист на 1500 видео, а видео №1054 удалено, и он перестает качать. Вот для этого ключ -i. Полезная привычка просто)